# Checking get_global_id in OpenCL Kernel Necessary?

Tags: opencl

I have noticed a number of kernel sources that look like this (found randomly by Googling):

```
__kernel void fill(__global float* array, unsigned int arrayLength, float val)
{
    if(get_global_id(0) < arrayLength)
    {
        array[get_global_id(0)] = val;
    }
}
```

My question is if that if-statement is actually necessary (assuming that "arrayLength" in this example is the same as the global work size).

In some of the more "professional" kernels I have seen, it is *not* present.  It also seems to me that the hardware would do well to not assign kernels to nonsense coordinates.

However, I also know that processors work in groups.  Hence, I can imagine that some processors of a group must do nothing (for example if you have 1 group of size 16, and a work size of 41, then the group would process the first 16 work items, then then next 16, then the next 9, with 7 processors not doing anything--do they get dummy kernels?).

I checked the [spec.](http://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/specs/opencl-1.1.pdf), and the only relevant mention of "get_global_id" is the same as the online documentation, which reads:

```
    The global work-item ID specifies the work-item ID based on the number of global work-items specified to execute the kernel.
```

. . . based *how*?

So what is it?  Is it safe to omit iff the array's size is a multiple of the work group size?  What?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the right answer already, I think.  If the global size of your kernel execution is the same as the array length, then this `if` statement is useless.

In general, that type of check is only needed for cases where you've partitioned your data in such a way that you *know* you might execute extra work items relative to your array size.  In my experience, you can almost always avoid such cases.